How can I restore Command+Left arrow in macOS?
I mapped Cmd+← to a new shortcut in the Keyboard Shortcuts area of System Settings, and now I can't figure out how to set it back to "go back to the start of the line." I have tried:

Changing the thing I'd mapped to Cmd+←  to something else.
Looking in Keyboard Shortcuts for anything that could possibly be the default behaviour for Cmd+←.
Hitting every "Restore Defaults" button I could find in the Keyboard Shortcuts menu.

None of this has worked. Incidentally, this also prevents me from using Cmd+← to go back to the previous page in Chrome.
I have the same problem with Cmd+→. I am using macOS Sonoma 14.6.

I know this sounds stupid but have you tried restarting/logging out of your user account? Some system settings can be stubborn and won't apply the change until you've restarted/logged out of your user account. You should also check if you bound the keyboard shortcuts to the whole system or individual apps, because if they are bound to individual apps, you'll need to delete them manually in system settings. Again, restart/log out once you've performed these actions

It isn't stupid if it works! I restarted and it was fine. You'd think after this many years of tech work I'd have thought of that. Thanks for the help!
